# Laravel chunk skipping 1 record from every chunk

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I have weird problem, using Laravel Excel and importing some data. I want to split import by chunks, but every time I define chunk size it skip 1 record from every chunk.

Here is peace of code:

```
Excel::selectSheets('Sheet1')->load($tmp_path)->chunk(3,function($result) use ($product)

foreach ($result as $row ) {
  $row->dump();
}

});
```

So I just splitting collection by 3 records to demonstrate problem, screen bellow

[image]

Update:

```
'import'     => [
  'heading' => false,
  'startRow' => 3
]
```

So if I define startRow I will see desired number of items per chunk, but unnecessary data at the beginning...

[image]

Comment: As mentioned in the doc `The chunk method breaks the collection into multiple, smaller collections of a given size:` so if you have 5 items in the parent collection it will be devided in 2 collections not 3 !!

Comment: Well actually I can define that size, this number represent number of items per chunk. Anyway the problem is somewhere in Excel package configuration startRow and heading. My whole data beggining from row 3 so I defined 'startRow'  => 3, but it seams that this settings applied to every collection.

Comment: To hepl you just describe the problem and give an input and expecting output and whet did you tried so far :)

Comment: Try to start from 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's seams that https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel have some problems with chunk method so I used Laravel chunk instead like this:

```
$tmp_path = $request->file('import_data')->getRealPath();
$results = Excel::load($tmp_path)->get();
$chunks = $results->chunk(3);
$chunks->toArray();
foreach ($chunks as $rows )
{
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        $row->dump();
    }
}
```